# Sql Query For GPS Tracking

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

this is my table with data
[SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/836b6/1)

it is tracking cars Table (i thing Column names is descriptive)
i get the lat-long of the car every 30 sec
now i want a report to get Trip-Idle Detail

[image: Report]

this is my last try

```
SELECT        carid, (SUM(CASE WHEN speed < 3 THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, b.trackold, b.TrackTime) END)) AS speeding, (SUM(CASE WHEN speed >= 3 THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, b.trackold, b.TrackTime) END)) 
 AS parked, round(sum(Distance / 1000), 2) AS Distance, TrackDay FROM            (SELECT        carid, TrackDay, TrackTime, trackold, speed, TrackDayOld, diff, Distance        FROM            (SELECT        carid, TrackTime, LAG(TrackTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY carid ORDER BY TrackTime) AS trackold, CONVERT(date, TrackTime) AS TrackDay, CONVERT(date, LAG(TrackTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY carid   ORDER BY TrackTime)) AS TrackDayOld, speed, datediff(minute, LAG(TrackTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY carid ORDER BY carid), TrackTime) AS diff, Distance FROM   T_Tracking) a WHERE        a.TrackDay = a.TrackDayOld) b GROUP BY carid, TrackDay
```

but that get a record per day for the car

Thank you

Comment: Is your `distance` column meant to be `null` in your sample data?

Comment: No you can try as it has float values this is old data

Comment: And what is your desired output here?  For the data in your question, what are the right results?

Comment: the report is showed in the picture my query return a single row per day per car where the desired should get details of the day i.e (driveing from 1:00 PM to 1:30 PM then stopped from 1:30 to 2:30

Comment: And what if the car is driving for a period, then stopped for a period, then driving for a period and then stopped again?  How are you going to show that on one row?

Comment: the drive period is a line with the drive time stopping is another line with its time which mean the total time is 24H driving or stopping as showed in image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here how i solved my problem
i will mark it as answer for any one searching for the same situation

```
SELECT        carid, (SUM(CASE WHEN speed < 3 THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, b.trackold, b.TrackTime) END)) AS speeding, (SUM(CASE WHEN speed >= 3 THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, b.trackold, b.TrackTime) END)) 
                     AS parked, round(sum(Distance / 1000), 2) AS Distance,TrackDay FROM    (SELECT        carid, TrackDay, TrackTime, trackold, speed, TrackDayOld, diff, Distance
                      FROM            (SELECT        carid, TrackTime, LAG(TrackTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY carid   ORDER BY TrackTime) AS trackold, CONVERT(date, TrackTime) AS TrackDay, CONVERT(date, LAG(TrackTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY carid  ORDER BY TrackTime)) AS TrackDayOld, speed, datediff(minute, LAG(TrackTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY carid ORDER BY carid), TrackTime) AS diff, Distance FROM  T_Tracking) a WHERE        a.TrackDay = a.TrackDayOld) b GROUP BY carid, TrackDay
```